# How to concat one string to other and write onclick action to it?

Tags: android

I am getting data from database in android. The data is nothing but a string(str1). Now after getting that data I want to add string2(str2) to str1. After adding I want to put
the onclick action for that str2. Can I do that in android? If so how can I achieve that task? Please help me with this task...

Will be really thankful....

Comment: Have you tried? Please share some code here

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "After adding I want to put the onclick action for that str2"? str2 is a String. onClick is for View. Do you mean onClick for a TextView which is displaying contents of str2?

Comment: In html we keep a hyperlink na..str2 is nothing but i want to put a word called "image". And if the image word is clicked the image in pop up should display...is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to add set the `String` in a `TextView` an add `onClick` action on it. Here's an example. Create this method in your activity.

```
private void setTextView(TextView t, String str1, String str2) {
    // Add str2 to str1 (append)
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(str1);
    s.append(str2);

    //Set text to textview
    t.setText(s.toString());

    //set onclicklistener.
    t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do whatever you want here. If you want
            // to show an image make an AlertDialog.
            // I have given link below.

        }
    });
}
```

Modify main.xml to contain a TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your Activty's onCreate add this :

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.string);
setTextView( t, str1, str2 );
```

AlertDialog with image : http://eventuallyconsistent.net/2011/07/28/create-an-android-dialog-with-an-image/

Answer (score 0):

Wriet this code in XML :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me"
    android:onClick="onClick"                
    android:clickable="true" />
```

In your Activity, write :

```
    TextView textActivity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String2 = String1 + "Some text";
    textActivity.setText(String2);
    textActivity.setOnClickListener(this);
    .....
    .....

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your problem, but my solution may help you.

Create a `TextView` & set `str2` as the `TextView` text.

```
myView.setText(str2);
```

now apply `onClickListener` on it.